# Limit your numbers by your runs

Tags: code-golf, array, decision-problem

### Self-limiting lists

Consider a nonempty list **L** containing nonnegative integers.
A *run* in **L** is a contiguous sublist of equal elements, which cannot be made longer.
For example, the runs of **[0,0,1,1,3,3,3,2,1,1]** are **[0,0], [1,1], [3,3,3], [2], [1,1]**.
The list **L** is *self-limiting* if for each integer **N ≥ 1**, the number of occurrences of **N** is less than or equal to the number of runs of **N-1**.
The above list is not self-limiting, because there are 4 occurrences of **1**, but only one run of **0**s.

Here's an example of a self-limiting list: **[0,0,3,4,1,0,2,1,1,0,2,1,0,0,0,1,0]**.
It has

- 5 runs of **0** and 5 occurrences of **1**,
- 4 runs of **1** and 2 occurrences of **2**,
- 2 runs of **2** and 1 occurrence of **3**,
- 1 run of **3** and 1 occurrence of **4**,
- 1 run of **4** and no occurrences of **5**,
- no occurrences of other integers.

### The task

Your task is to decide whether a list is self-limiting.
More explicitly, your input shall be a nonempty list of nonnegative integers.
If the list is self-limiting, your output shall be truthy; otherwise, it shall be falsy.
Input and output can be in any reasonable format.

The lowest byte count in each programming language is the winner.
Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply.

### Test cases

Truthy instances:

```
[0]
[1,0]
[0,1,1,0,2]
[3,1,1,0,0,2,0,0]
[5,0,4,1,3,0,2,2,0,1,1,1,0]
[0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,2,2,0,0]
[6,0,0,0,2,2,1,0,5,0,3,4,0,1,1,1]
[5,0,1,0,0,0,0,4,0,3,1,1,1,2,2,0,0,0,0,0]
[4,5,1,3,2,0,5,2,0,3,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,3,4,4,0,2,6,0,2,6]
[0,4,1,3,10,6,0,1,3,7,9,5,5,0,7,4,2,2,5,0,1,3,8,8,11,0,0,6,2,1,1,2,0,4]
```

Falsy instances:

```
[2]
[1,1,0]
[0,0,1,1,1,0,0,2]
[0,1,0,1,1,2,2,3,0,0,4,6]
[1,1,2,1,2,0,2,0,3,0,0,2,2,1,2,3,2,0,1,1,1,0,0,3,3,0]
[3,4,1,0,0,0,5,5,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,1,1,0,4,3,5,4,3]
[1,0,0,0,2,5,3,1,1,0,3,3,1,3,5,4,0,4,0,0,2,0,2,1,1,5,0,0,2,4,4,0,2,0,1,4,4,2,3,3,5,3,4,0,2,0,5]
[4,3,1,0,0,4,6,6,1,0,1,2,1,3,0,1,0,2,0,3,4,0,2,1,1,3,0,2,2,2,0,5,5,0,5,2,5,5,0,4,3,2,3,1,1,3,5,1,4,1,6,2,6,2,4,0,4,0,4,5,3,3,0,0,6,1,0,0,0,6,2,1,0,1,2,6,2,4]
[5,1,1,1,0,2,0,6,1,0,2,1,2,2,5,3,1,0,0,0,3,2,3,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,2,0,6,4,1,2,1,1,6,4,1,2,2,4,0,1,2,2,1,3,0,1,2,0,0,0,2,0,2,2,0,1,0,0,1,3,0,0,0,6,2,0,1,0,1,2,1,1,1,0,4,0,0,5,2,0,0,0,4,1,2,2,2,2,0,5,3,2,4,5,0,5]
```

Comment: Not to be a bother, but please consider using one of the approaches from [this meta discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12305/31625) instead of truthy/falsy, as truthiness isn't a property of more than a couple languages used here often.

Comment: @LeakyNun Yes, otherwise the condition fails for those **N** for which **N-1** is not present.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder There's `[2]` too, but such cases should be falsy, yeah.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I hadn't seen that discussion, thanks for linking it. I'll keep this challenge as it is though, because I want to process the approaches discussed there for a while.

Comment: Sure, but I would like to keep the comment there, since I feel like a lot of people have missed it. It matters quite a lot, at least for me, in posting in languages like Retina.

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 29 bytes

```perl6
{bag(.grep(?*)X-1)⊆.squish}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVPNSsNAEL73KUIRaSXK7uxuqhTx5hN4EEKQCm0VKtaEHop49eBj@iJx5zdRZGGzO7Mz833fTPbrdlf1L8fidFNc9@@Pq@3sYtuu97Obs/n9uZ9/f31edG@H5@7po@9Wx2Ja37WHdTNdTvC2mZ08zIvNazupXVNOal/Sx5U@L1cCXoJc8hV3NKV8iNkYyIhmz4842FnEEGmxFRnYhE7MFXI2yaHpvTxz5ApSQPLwwqcxxyMOoExATzlYE3jbsUqkyhXvjJaJeEdWPC7Kq5wLQSyyE0sm8Vzm5TlhRfA9lYwNqzmtb1e77j9xgcX9o5Boo4o7oxiEeKVhIJWUoMoHQn3IFtDPbYumAbP5JZ6FYZ2Q/XmXCRB3KrXzgU78iPvhBA36k9xVXEwbSbhAMcHsiTsWBFfmlxfzBpkmbySjFdApA2OSCF4S7CBAA80Csq6ox2BwI8EI0jilWMkEen3Ns6dagj0GaUsy6E7KqoRD8zAmCiFvZ5ABhxFRGDVCfyIngzYAdCOBtF3Oht3JjwgjgQJVI5maZf8D)

Very nice challenge for Perl 6. Uses the subset operator on [Bags](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Bag) (integer-weighted sets). Explanation:

```perl6
{
    bag(           # Create bag of
        .grep(?*)  # non-zero elements,
        X- 1       # decremented by one.
    )
    ⊆              # Subset test.
    .squish        # "squish" removes repeated elements in each run.
                   # The result is implicitly converted to a bag
                   # counting the number of runs.
}
```

Comment: Beautiful. I saw the Bag+subset approach but stuck on the thing to compare to.

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, <s>49</s> <s>48</s> 44 bytes

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
$z[$_+1]+=!/^$o$/;$z[$o=$_]--}{$_="@z"!~/.-/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/1@lKlolXtswVttWUT9OJV9F3xokkm@rEh@rq1tbrRJvq@RQpaRYp6@nq///vwGXCZchlzGXoQGXGZcBmGnOZcllCoQGQJYJlxEQmkJlLIDQ0BDIASk2AgoZAkmQCf/yC0oy8/OK/@sWAAA)

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>92</s> 89 bytes

```javascript
a=>a.map(n=>g(~n,n!=p&&g(p=n)),c=[j=0],p=g=n=>c[n]=-~c[n])&&!c.some((n,i)=>i-j++|n<c[~j])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVTbTgIxEH33L3jB3VhIr4smlke/wLfNPmxWQAh2N6ImJoZfx850WpZYTJNSOrcz50x31361h@59O3zMXP@yOq3tqbXLdv7WDoWzy01xdMxN7DCdborBurJkna13ljdssBvrPbraNXZ2hJ9yOp1080P/tioKx7alXW5nu7u7H/fY1cddU5663h36/Wq@7zfFbf38/vnx@t3cljfj@3VR86b8cydY7pYz4RdnMmNTZPNW2DMext9r76PQB7xEiMlW4infOe@1zBXagwf4QiXla1GFK1gERXH0VISGqoSVidQ@O/QgsY7EyJAr5hNpBwwacVVhz3YaOBEcneC4YA8@NUBceCMAMmS590uE/BX2KhCBhrw3l3I/tftDTm2ZVft/FYj/KxPBE2@K2Kyu1JCEN7IWFZPE57mWAnt2ynTiOVB0oVfKAiiUt/s9P93kbVicW4WnEBMmghNWsBv6H/WEKhrFURij0r3Jzowi1J4bvwJnkt6CSIzoVC@@EZn6NIjWUGeScCucRuCkwimTCb1GVIpmJXZc0QsR0Tv7NqIOMsVKUtikTjihiHyf5wBiNPUn0lnSe5SjvuVItfhF4DTqZ7x8xFfUlqfXx@mrIkd8KaxmSI3TLw)

#### How?

The array **c[ ]** is used to store both the number of runs and the number of integer occurrences. Runs are stored at non-negative indices and integer occurrences are stored at 1's-complement indices (**c[-1]** = number of **0**'s, **c[-2]** = number of **1**'s, etc.).

Negative indices are actually saved as *properties* of the underlying array object and **.some()** does not iterate over them.

```javascript
a =>                        // given the input array a[]
  a.map(n =>                // for each value n in a[]:
    g(                      //   update c[]:
      ~n,                   //     increment c[~n] (# of integer occurrences)
      n != p && g(p = n)    //     if n != p, set p to n and increment c[n] (# of runs)
    ),                      //   end of c[] update
    c = [j = 0],            //   start with c = [0] and j = 0 (used later)
    p =                     //   initialize p to a non-numeric value
    g = n => c[n] = -~c[n]  //   g = helper function to increment c[n]
  )                         // end of map()
  && !c.some((n, i) =>      // for each value n at position i in c[]:
    i - j++ |               //   make sure that i == j++
    n < c[~j]               //   and n is greater than or equal to c[~j]
  )                         // end of some()
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
œ-ŒgḢ€‘ƊS¬
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVO7TQRBDM2p4gpYJI89swcVUADhakOEhK4BMnQJEiEkxMRXwMWgow@ukcX/WYRWGs348/ye7X242@0el@X0dnl6vf85fpz3h/PT@/fL7edh@XqW1/5wsyzTNME8XGw2Uxn8AkPhDwa0J/mTDXKasfG1spnULI5iYQEBmdWzV/mjmswobsEjRnScXqR4IKiTvIxj2WfBlTGEDyoaarClB0TJUypVrT7aGaxNUgG1y3U7XDOaENmyU8o291zxVwxyVBFFi9ZZsKYJo6n/euLd6L2GlEQudOzJ6LghKFqGLrUjkvhjZDVVG/s/DctEqUXs5zN3wAPaEHMnvVmYTQGckfibv6OhAly1VaQ5lPYWcyLnxjr5M/3ou1RSas0SsWOYapoSbM4fnSrpBojyUSeLSbgqEfJhhcjRd69EdGxd9BQzHH1ALcmDF45G9jFKTnVJJe/oy40rqbgaR/xE4OvVKcKqRTE0yCUH/xFx1SLSatqoeZ5/AQ)

#### How it works

```
œ-ŒgḢ€‘ƊS¬  Main link. Argument: A (array)

       Ɗ    Drei; group the three links to the left into a monadic chain.
  Œg          Group consecutive, identical elements of A into subarrays.
    Ḣ€        Head each; pop the first element of each run.
      ‘       Increment the extracted integers.
            The resulting array contains n repeated once for each run of (n-1)'s.
œ-          Perform multiset subtraction, removing one occurrence of n for each
            run of (n-1)'s.
       S    Take the sum. If only 0's remain, the sum will be 0.
        ¬   Take the logical NOT, mapping 0 to 1 and positive integers to 0.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 19 bytes

```
ŒgḢ€ċÐ€ṀḶ$<ċÐ€ṀR$$Ẹ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVM7TsRADO05x5ZTOPZMFiROQbvaEiGhvQAdoqGgQRyBmhottAsHCRcJY/vZCWik@cS/956d2@vD4W6ev19upuPrz8Pb19PpuR/Tx/10fN9cLs@rzWb6PM6nx/6c592OChUptQz95L7HSbb6uS9nO9viHk76EDw0htze@kXTiX3k4v4ZTBmxRGbsiLIMCA3gkCPSBzoyk6AA8vhS19rjFQdbJjZXD17Rw65VqlUefXe0TmQg@6rXbbnouRTEthu1ZIPlvK/BE45QUktWTcSu3z8RQD9EpWQh4DZGGCNZcAiFGOyWbKJ270xNmg74jz4ZpnWk2/uOJsPcSjRX7OZOLjkBjdob3qGfpq2mjViM5PfmTRHg6vz6ct6MgRmSZM0CMUicTJrBa8DOACrWbmU9Whs54VaDIehNUBwxZEN4@3gN@ROEM6MtLaETyoaES/M0poLQkHfGDPOKKK8aEf8JYZYWgLQSKNpFOc@Ef41XAolVM5n2@18)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 94 bytes

```python
lambda a:all(sum(1for x,y in zip(a,a[1:]+[-1])if x==j!=y)>=a.count(j+1)for j in range(max(a)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVPbbsIwDH2Gr@jeUtFNuZYNqfuKvbFqyjYYRaVUHWywn2e246SgSCH15fgc2/Tnw2bfmcu6er20fvf@6TO/8G0rvo87odb7ITsV56zpsr@mF77wS7WoZ8t7VefNOjtV1fauOufPlX/42B@7g9jOVI5JW0wZfPe1Ejt/Ej7P88vvpmlX2ctwXC2mk6Z7yyoI6o8HkU8n/dBA9lqsfnwrwIfxS1lPl6rAWxYKjiw0vA2/4QtvsDj4tWAzZEOrCjGUKVP8mBczS/oOFvQhkgEsRmBsxVGSPIbRGSUciLSQjRw04WiKDLkxX6Uba1iqW4abmAYNSpIRn/PiCaCQwhycWNCx5xGOCnglcVdU0QKOpq7dqmfd3EmZ@BtWVXKOZpzIPnZGs64Ry6CfpmGTvkD1pi8pC6sY8MMdpspeV8R5GnqFmNBpyVzQ7/g79g1RLTXFUI5JdkezMMwKtMEJmjXviEoKbcKPu6OTDkfsHDPXzNPQlFFzSdPTia0lFoZnEhWWvFkqRtNOxT7qFKt5Ii4xl1w19m@cG@ZY1qPSW/Pe6iud@moK8Z8heYVGfvKqP3FWMm2x5H@XvuqPoWrUpfof)

Comment: `sum(1for ... if x==j!=y)` => `sum(x==j!=y for ...)`.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder oh ofc. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 17 bytes

```
ŒgḢ€ċ’}<ċ
çÐ€x⁸ẸṆ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opPSHOxY9alpzpPtRw8xamyPdXIeXH54AFKh41Ljj4a4dD3e2/f//P9pUxxAMDXSMgNgMyjIEYiMdUx1jMB8EjYF8YyANUWsIZUH0mIBZID6MbQSkDaAsQ6g@I6hJRmBsBDXFACpvADbJCG62EdxdJmA5U7h@mA0QM0zBLjMB0kB2LAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 21 bytes

```
x o e@ó¥ mÌè¥X ¨Uè¥XÄ
```

[Test it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=eCBvIGVA86UgbczopVggqFXopVjE&input=WzAsMCwzLDQsMSwwLDIsMSwxLDAsMiwxLDAsMCwwLDEsMF0=)

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <s>13</s> 9 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

Dennis [found a much better algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/160001/527).  I've shamelessly ported it to stax.

```
ä╨²@┬↕OR♣
```

[Run and debug it online](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=84d0fd40c2124f5205&i=[0]%0A[1,0]%0A[0,1,1,0,2]%0A[3,1,1,0,0,2,0,0]%0A[5,0,4,1,3,0,2,2,0,1,1,1,0]%0A[0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,2,2,0,0]%0A[6,0,0,0,2,2,1,0,5,0,3,4,0,1,1,1]%0A[5,0,1,0,0,0,0,4,0,3,1,1,1,2,2,0,0,0,0,0]%0A[4,5,1,3,2,0,5,2,0,3,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,3,4,4,0,2,6,0,2,6]%0A[0,4,1,3,10,6,0,1,3,7,9,5,5,0,7,4,2,2,5,0,1,3,8,8,11,0,0,6,2,1,1,2,0,4]%0A[2]%0A[1,1,0]%0A[0,0,1,1,1,0,0,2]%0A[0,1,0,1,1,2,2,3,0,0,4,6]%0A[1,1,2,1,2,0,2,0,3,0,0,2,2,1,2,3,2,0,1,1,1,0,0,3,3,0]%0A[3,4,1,0,0,0,5,5,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,1,1,0,4,3,5,4,3]%0A[1,0,0,0,2,5,3,1,1,0,3,3,1,3,5,4,0,4,0,0,2,0,2,1,1,5,0,0,2,4,4,0,2,0,1,4,4,2,3,3,5,3,4,0,2,0,5]%0A[4,3,1,0,0,4,6,6,1,0,1,2,1,3,0,1,0,2,0,3,4,0,2,1,1,3,0,2,2,2,0,5,5,0,5,2,5,5,0,4,3,2,3,1,1,3,5,1,4,1,6,2,6,2,4,0,4,0,4,5,3,3,0,0,6,1,0,0,0,6,2,1,0,1,2,6,2,4]%0A[5,1,1,1,0,2,0,6,1,0,2,1,2,2,5,3,1,0,0,0,3,2,3,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,2,0,6,4,1,2,1,1,6,4,1,2,2,4,0,1,2,2,1,3,0,1,2,0,0,0,2,0,2,2,0,1,0,0,1,3,0,0,0,6,2,0,1,0,1,2,1,1,1,0,4,0,0,5,2,0,0,0,4,1,2,2,2,2,0,5,3,2,4,5,0,5]%0A&a=1&m=2)

Unpacked, ungolfed, and commented, this is what it looks like.

```
c   copy input
:g  get run elements
{^m increment each
|-  multiset-subtract from original input
|M! get maximum from result, and apply logical not
```

[Run this one](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=c%09copy+input%0A%3Ag%09get+run+elements%0A%7B%5Em%09increment+each%0A%7C-%09multiset-subtract+from+original+input%0A%7CM%21%09get+maximum+from+result,+and+apply+logical+not&i=[0]%0A[1,0]%0A[0,1,1,0,2]%0A[3,1,1,0,0,2,0,0]%0A[5,0,4,1,3,0,2,2,0,1,1,1,0]%0A[0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,2,2,0,0]%0A[6,0,0,0,2,2,1,0,5,0,3,4,0,1,1,1]%0A[5,0,1,0,0,0,0,4,0,3,1,1,1,2,2,0,0,0,0,0]%0A[4,5,1,3,2,0,5,2,0,3,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,3,4,4,0,2,6,0,2,6]%0A[0,4,1,3,10,6,0,1,3,7,9,5,5,0,7,4,2,2,5,0,1,3,8,8,11,0,0,6,2,1,1,2,0,4]%0A[2]%0A[1,1,0]%0A[0,0,1,1,1,0,0,2]%0A[0,1,0,1,1,2,2,3,0,0,4,6]%0A[1,1,2,1,2,0,2,0,3,0,0,2,2,1,2,3,2,0,1,1,1,0,0,3,3,0]%0A[3,4,1,0,0,0,5,5,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,1,1,0,4,3,5,4,3]%0A[1,0,0,0,2,5,3,1,1,0,3,3,1,3,5,4,0,4,0,0,2,0,2,1,1,5,0,0,2,4,4,0,2,0,1,4,4,2,3,3,5,3,4,0,2,0,5]%0A[4,3,1,0,0,4,6,6,1,0,1,2,1,3,0,1,0,2,0,3,4,0,2,1,1,3,0,2,2,2,0,5,5,0,5,2,5,5,0,4,3,2,3,1,1,3,5,1,4,1,6,2,6,2,4,0,4,0,4,5,3,3,0,0,6,1,0,0,0,6,2,1,0,1,2,6,2,4]%0A[5,1,1,1,0,2,0,6,1,0,2,1,2,2,5,3,1,0,0,0,3,2,3,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,2,0,6,4,1,2,1,1,6,4,1,2,2,4,0,1,2,2,1,3,0,1,2,0,0,0,2,0,2,2,0,1,0,0,1,3,0,0,0,6,2,0,1,0,1,2,1,1,1,0,4,0,0,5,2,0,0,0,4,1,2,2,2,2,0,5,3,2,4,5,0,5]%0A&a=1&m=2)

**Old Answer:**

```
║Ä|╤#╫∩▼cëózü
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=ba8e7cd123d7ef1f6389a27a81&i=[0]%0A[1,0]%0A[0,1,1,0,2]%0A[3,1,1,0,0,2,0,0]%0A[5,0,4,1,3,0,2,2,0,1,1,1,0]%0A[0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,2,2,0,0]%0A[6,0,0,0,2,2,1,0,5,0,3,4,0,1,1,1]%0A[5,0,1,0,0,0,0,4,0,3,1,1,1,2,2,0,0,0,0,0]%0A[4,5,1,3,2,0,5,2,0,3,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,3,4,4,0,2,6,0,2,6]%0A[0,4,1,3,10,6,0,1,3,7,9,5,5,0,7,4,2,2,5,0,1,3,8,8,11,0,0,6,2,1,1,2,0,4]%0A[2]%0A[1,1,0]%0A[0,0,1,1,1,0,0,2]%0A[0,1,0,1,1,2,2,3,0,0,4,6]%0A[1,1,2,1,2,0,2,0,3,0,0,2,2,1,2,3,2,0,1,1,1,0,0,3,3,0]%0A[3,4,1,0,0,0,5,5,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,1,1,0,4,3,5,4,3]%0A[1,0,0,0,2,5,3,1,1,0,3,3,1,3,5,4,0,4,0,0,2,0,2,1,1,5,0,0,2,4,4,0,2,0,1,4,4,2,3,3,5,3,4,0,2,0,5]%0A[4,3,1,0,0,4,6,6,1,0,1,2,1,3,0,1,0,2,0,3,4,0,2,1,1,3,0,2,2,2,0,5,5,0,5,2,5,5,0,4,3,2,3,1,1,3,5,1,4,1,6,2,6,2,4,0,4,0,4,5,3,3,0,0,6,1,0,0,0,6,2,1,0,1,2,6,2,4]%0A[5,1,1,1,0,2,0,6,1,0,2,1,2,2,5,3,1,0,0,0,3,2,3,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,2,0,6,4,1,2,1,1,6,4,1,2,2,4,0,1,2,2,1,3,0,1,2,0,0,0,2,0,2,2,0,1,0,0,1,3,0,0,0,6,2,0,1,0,1,2,1,1,1,0,4,0,0,5,2,0,0,0,4,1,2,2,2,2,0,5,3,2,4,5,0,5]%0A&a=1&m=2)

It iterates over the input and checks the conditions:

- Is the element `> 0`?
- Is `occurrences(element) >= runs(element - 1)`?

If either of these conditions are true for an element, then that element is compliant.  Iff all elements are compliant, the result is `1`.

Here's the unpacked, ungolfed, commented representation of the same program.

```
O           push 1 under the input
F           iterate over the input using the rest of program
  |c        skip this iteration of the value is 0
  x#        number of occurrences of this value in input (a)
  x:g _v#   number of runs of (current-1) in input (b)
  >!        not (a > b); this will be truthy iff this element is compliant
  *         multiply with running result
```

[Run this one](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=O++++++++%09push+1+under+the+input%0AF++++++++%09iterate+over+the+input+using+the+rest+of+program%0A++%7Cc+++++%09skip+this+iteration+of+the+value+is+0%0A++x%23+++++%09number+of+occurrences+of+this+value+in+input+%28a%29%0A++x%3Ag+_v%23%09number+of+runs+of+%28current-1%29+in+input+%28b%29%0A++%3E%21+++++%09not+%28a+%3E+b%29%3B+this+will+be+truthy+iff+this+element+is+compliant%0A++*++++++%09multiply+with+running+result&i=[0]%0A[1,0]%0A[0,1,1,0,2]%0A[3,1,1,0,0,2,0,0]%0A[5,0,4,1,3,0,2,2,0,1,1,1,0]%0A[0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,2,2,0,0]%0A[6,0,0,0,2,2,1,0,5,0,3,4,0,1,1,1]%0A[5,0,1,0,0,0,0,4,0,3,1,1,1,2,2,0,0,0,0,0]%0A[4,5,1,3,2,0,5,2,0,3,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,3,4,4,0,2,6,0,2,6]%0A[0,4,1,3,10,6,0,1,3,7,9,5,5,0,7,4,2,2,5,0,1,3,8,8,11,0,0,6,2,1,1,2,0,4]%0A[2]%0A[1,1,0]%0A[0,0,1,1,1,0,0,2]%0A[0,1,0,1,1,2,2,3,0,0,4,6]%0A[1,1,2,1,2,0,2,0,3,0,0,2,2,1,2,3,2,0,1,1,1,0,0,3,3,0]%0A[3,4,1,0,0,0,5,5,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,1,1,0,4,3,5,4,3]%0A[1,0,0,0,2,5,3,1,1,0,3,3,1,3,5,4,0,4,0,0,2,0,2,1,1,5,0,0,2,4,4,0,2,0,1,4,4,2,3,3,5,3,4,0,2,0,5]%0A[4,3,1,0,0,4,6,6,1,0,1,2,1,3,0,1,0,2,0,3,4,0,2,1,1,3,0,2,2,2,0,5,5,0,5,2,5,5,0,4,3,2,3,1,1,3,5,1,4,1,6,2,6,2,4,0,4,0,4,5,3,3,0,0,6,1,0,0,0,6,2,1,0,1,2,6,2,4]%0A[5,1,1,1,0,2,0,6,1,0,2,1,2,2,5,3,1,0,0,0,3,2,3,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,2,0,6,4,1,2,1,1,6,4,1,2,2,4,0,1,2,2,1,3,0,1,2,0,0,0,2,0,2,2,0,1,0,0,1,3,0,0,0,6,2,0,1,0,1,2,1,1,1,0,4,0,0,5,2,0,0,0,4,1,2,2,2,2,0,5,3,2,4,5,0,5]%0A&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 80 bytes

```
import Data.List
o#l=[1|x<-l,x==o]
f x=and[(i-1)#(head<$>group x)>=i#x|i<-x,i>0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVTBbsIwDL3zFZHgAFKZEicpm0Q57bg/QBwqAaNaoQg6qQf@vYsdJy20U6Qoje3n52enp/z@cyjLti3O1@pWi8@8zt@@ins9qaZltlWPZr0skybLqt3kKJosv@y382KpFtP56ZDv17PN9636vYpmscmKafMo1ssmKTZy157z4iIysa8mQlxvxaUWM3EUW7l7/lbJ641MlFsygZd7zffOgvuL1bo74@ya7OihvP8AXUacDm8MMSWbt6IfZtAuByOP5FccIclLMwNG9@slyjhU5AyEDxTlcQKWijvmNsQn9fugMl@/kuSAx1Xy4WCR2soZkYhly7tbymOnVJ@i7AYxn2Fh0LD/RWU5RxoqoxSaBUpHcIFpBCGC@MASdTk02gcDYqJsvuon6SMCZtfO7vbhMLKnTcK4aTp5f99YyRzRbvk7tAYzGNJaU4yO93bQes1snRZueY2AR1hFFUzMFUYbYn2WmFquCJizpqFCLVIaFojMDTHS3PZQbcoDroL3YLSD7hDjgLtpYxWSGQSNu55jjOHaVDwDPyXo1Qy9ToVHLHliO66yp1Xop4wPSPKPAHpaacpmfRfaPw)